# RTS Engine or DotA-like game

Tags: c++, rts

Is there any good **documented** and **simple** Game engine for RTS games, especially for building DotA-like game?

I know I can use Crystal Space, Irrlicht or another Game Engine. But I need most similar game or engine to DotA gameplay.

Comment: Irrlicht is just a rendering engine. You would still need to write the game play portion of it.

Comment: Which technology to use questions are considered off topic here.

Answer (score 12):

The Warcraft III and Starcraft II editors are probably, almost by definition, the best engines to make DotA-like games in. They are reasonably well documented, simpler than anything suggested thus far, and have a proven record of being able to make excellent RTS games.

Comment: Warcraft III editor and "engine" have very much limitations, such as interface, hotkey system, etc... I'm looking for C++ engine.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "interface", but if you look at many of the Starcraft II editor examples, they don't look anything like Starcraft's UI. DotA itself was made in the WC3 engine, so the "interface" can certainly support a DotA-like game.

Comment: You and your future players will both have to own the game, which a big minus in my opinion. Blizzard should release a SDK like Unreal did, even if only an outdated and old version, I think it would be awesome. Sell licenses to people who want to develop commercially for it, and keep it free for hobbyists.

Answer (score 9):

[Spring RTS engine](http://springrts.com/) looks very nice.
[Stratagus](http://stratagus.sourceforge.net/) is another option.

Both the above came from the search 'c++ RTS engine'.

Answer (score 7):

Glest, especially [MegaGlest](http://megaglest.org/) and the [Glest Advanced Engine](http://glest.org/glest_board/index.php?topic=6411.0) ([forums](http://glest.org/glest_board/))

[image]

Its a classic RTS engine that is fairly straightforward to 'mod' and add 'factions' using 3D models and XML files to define the unit attributes.  It can be used as a basis for 'total conversions' and the code-base is accessible enough to add specific features.  It may be that you don't actually need to touch the code, however - its designed to be modded!

[MegaGlest 3.4](http://glest.org/glest_board/index.php?topic=6460.0) has just reached beta - its an awesome engine that's approachable to modding.

Comment: I checked this. Glest work's very slow, especially on my ubuntu. Is this design problem or specific?

Comment: Seems likely to be your machine setup.  Try MegaGlest, it has lots of rendering performance improvements though.

Answer (score 3):

The [Neoaxis](http://www.neoaxisgroup.com/) Engine might be an idea.  When I was evaluating it, I recall that part of the demo involved an RTS.  It's general purpose, and may be a little raw for what you want, though.