# Help me choose an engine

Tags: python, rts

So far i've been trying to make a RTS in pygame but, i feel like 2d is not enough and pygame has me do a lot of stuff that i would not like doing. What i would like doing is working on the AI gameplay and such and not worying too much about how to display stuff,physics and the like too much.

So far Unity has boo which is supposed to be similar to python i wonder if that could work. How similar is it to python should i use this?
Other options as far as i can see are ogre3d python bindings and UDK.

Which would best suit my needs?

Comment: For any information about: Boo (for usage with Unity):
http://boo.codehaus.org/Gotchas+for+Python+Users
Boo != Python, rather Boo > Python.

Comment: Boo is a great language, however it is almost undocumented. I tried more than once to use it with Unity3D, but C# always turned out much easier and almost as powerful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, if you don't want to worry about other aspects EXCEPT graphics (physics, etc), forget about using Ogre. It's a graphics engine, not a *game* engine.

Unity has all of the aspects that you want already in there and can offer you a quick turnaround time.

The UDK is a good one, but it does involve a bit more work to get up and running before you can focus on the AI and gameplay aspects.

If your aim is to get something up and running in a very short amount of time, go for Unity. If you don't like Boo (which personally I have no experience in whatsoever), you can always use the C# and/or Javascript alternatives.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like what you want is to just do the actual meat of your game. To use the smallest amount of boilerplate, I would use Unity.

Boo seems a mixture of C# and Python, to me. It shouldn't be difficult to pick up (and there's always Javascript too).

If you don't want to go to Unity or UDK or another editor-type program, there is this question [about RTS engines (though this is C++)](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/7602/rts-engine-or-dota-like-game)

Answer (score 0):

see [Spring RTS](http://www.springrts.com), it is a good engine with a lot of games runing over it (that means a lot of examples), it is open source and written in C/C++ with LUA over it.