# Open Source Engine for RTS

Tags: opengl

I must write a cross-platform real-time-strategy game within 2-3 months. I want use C++ and OpenGL and am looking for an engine.

The engine must be open source and work under both Linux and Windows. Preferably it should work with 3ds Max models. I do not know the game engines. Which engine would you recommend?

Comment: Exact duplicate of http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/7602/rts-engine-or-dota-like-game

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I know of three that still seem reasonably actively developed: [Spring](http://springrts.com/), [OpenRA](http://openra.res0l.net/) and [Stratagus](http://stratagus.sourceforge.net/). Wikipedia has a [list of open source game engines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_game_engines#Free_and_open_source), some of which may be appropriate for an RTS game (such as [FIFE](http://fifengine.net/), which used to bill itself as a Fallout-style engine, but should still be appropriate for RTS games).

Some of these engines may work directly with 3DS Max model files, but that file format (.3ds) is actually pretty archaic, cumbersome, and suboptimal for direct consumption by a game engine, so you may find that the engines instead support some other model format that Max can export to (or supply their own conversion tools).

Also, it's not open source (<s>and does in fact cost money</s> might cost if you need certain features), but [people have used Unity](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/17634-C-amp-C-style-RTS-Community-Project-Generals) to make RTS games as well.

Comment: Unity is actually free to use, unless you need any of the 'Pro' features (90% of people don't), or need to export to something like an iOS device.

Comment: Er, yes. You're right, I don't know why I said that because I even have it installed on one of my home machines... >_<  Fixed it.

Comment: You say there are two, but list 3. Is one not developed actively? ;-)

Comment: Look I didn't have my coffee this morning! Fixed! :D

Answer (score 2):

There is also [Glest](http://glest.org/en/index.php).

Comment: Glest is being actively developed, check the forums!

Answer (score 0):

[Irrlicht](http://irrlicht.sourceforge.net/) is a great open-source 3D game engine. It doesn't have RTS-specific features but it could certainly be used to create an RTS (or any kind of game).

It's written in C++, runs on Windows or Linux and supports both OpenGL and DirectX.

Irrlicht is